# Sending an authorization/credentials header with the Adafruit FONA

Tags: hardware, communication, gps

I would like to be able to send POST calls to a server that is protected, and thus need to set an authorization header like [so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). However, it does not seem to appear anywhere in the [docs](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/sim800_series_at_command_manual_v1.01.pdf).

Does anyone have any insight on an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to byte-bang it out manually over tcp. You'd use the **at+cipstart** command from the manual you referenced...

See this thread for a bunch of useful info - http://www.edaboard.com/thread126547.html